# Live WooCommerce Product Search Form using AJAX (Shortcode)

Tags: javascript, ajax, woocommerce

While the search form works, I need help fixing the problem that occurs when the form is empty after having been typed into.

**What I mean is this:**
If you start typing a search query, you start to get results. This part works fine.
But if you, while / after typing, remove the text from the search form - you get a list of ALL products.

It should only show results if and when typing and show nothing if and when empty.

**Fix:**
After applying a modified version of the solution offered and provided by Terminator-Barbapapa as per below, it works as intended.

The code below might not be 100% correct, but it works.

**The code so far:**

```
    add_shortcode('live_search', 'live_search_function');
    function live_search_function() { ?>
    
        <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>
    
        <div id="productfetch"></div>
    
        <?php
    }
    
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function fetch() {
            
            if( document.getElementById('keyword').value.trim().length == 0 ) {

                jQuery('#productfetch').html('');

            } else {

                jQuery.ajax( {

                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
                    success: function(data) {
                        jQuery('#productfetch').html( data );
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    </script>
<?php
}
    
    add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'product_fetch');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','product_fetch');
    function product_fetch() {
    
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
    
        if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        
        <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
            <?php endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
    die();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check in your `fetch()` function to see if your input field is empty. If so, clear the `datafetch` div, else run your AJAX.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        function fetch() {
            
            if( document.getElementById('keyword').value.trim().length == 0 ) {

                jQuery('#productfetch').html('');

            } else {

                jQuery.ajax( {

                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
                    success: function(data) {
                        jQuery('#productfetch').html( data );
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion and that is what I was looking for. I kind of understand what you did, but unfortunately - it did not work.

Comment: After changing this: `if( document.getElementById('keyword').value.trim().length === 0 ) {` into this: `if( document.getElementById('keyword').value.trim().length == 0 ) {` it did work.

I am not sure that is the 100% correct approach, but I will use it for now. Thank you for "pointing" me in the right direction.

Comment: I believe the `length` function should return an integer so `===` should work. But `==` will do the trick just as well. It then just doesn't care about the type of value that is returned, as long as it is zero. Glad this fixed your issue. (Edited my answer.)